# how to factor an equation by completing the square?

Tags: sympy

I would like to factor an equation by completing the square:

```
>>>> import sympy
>>>> x, c = symbols('x c')
>>>> factor(x**2 - 4*x  - 1)
x**2 - 4*x - 1
```

However, I was expecting to see:

```
(x - 2)**2 - 5
```

How can this be done in sympy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a circumstance like that you can get the factors using `solve`:

```
>>> solve(x**2-4*x-1)
[2 + sqrt(5), -sqrt(5) + 2]
```

I would not expect `factor` to give me the factors in the form suggested in the question. However, if you really want to 'complete the square' sympy will do the arithmetic for you (you need to know the steps) but not much more, AFAIK.

Comment: I am eager to learn how to do those arithmetic steps with sympy. I do know the algorithm for completing the squares, but I am not proficient with sympy. Is there any good tutorial you can point me in?

Comment: @LudvigH: You might be better off posting this as a question (rather than a comment), so that it's more likely to be seen by more people. As it happens I can't offer an answer.

Answer (score 9):

The approach I went with in the end was:

```
>>> h, k, x = symbols('h k x')
>>> solve( (x-h)**2 - k  - (x**2-4*x-1), [h,k] )
[(2, 5)]
# so h = 2 and k = 5
# (x-2)**2 - 5
```

Source: https://minireference.com/static/tutorials/sympy_tutorial.pdf

Comment: Chris, great of you to come back and give the correct answer, but there is a typo that's giving the wrong solution. It should be `solve( (x-h)**2 + k  - (x**2-4*x-1), [h,k] )`. Should be + k, not - k.